# Selecting south-facing slopes with slope > 10° using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, dem, slope, aspect

I have to make a Model in the Model Builder which will **select the areas with slope bigger than 10°** and which are **facing to the south**. It should be used for environmentalist who will just insert a DEM and the model will automatically display only these wanted areas.

How do I do that?

I already used tools Slope to and Aspect, but I don't know how to select only that values which I want to display and make a Model for that.

Comment: Did you try adding a raster calculator step with [`Con()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/conditional-evaluation-with-con.htm) function?

Comment: Not yet, I don't know how exactly this expression works. I'll try to find explanation somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you want to expose your model parameters, it's all in the help file [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/creating-model-parameter.htm).

Comment: The reclassify tool would work here. It would allow you to group all cells >10 and <10 into two categories. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm

Comment: @Map man : you should put it into an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the workflow I would recommend:

> 1. Bring in your DEM
> 2. Run the [Slope](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/slope.htm) tool
> 3. Run the [Reclassify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm) tool, so that cell values >=10 = 1, and <10 = 0
> 4. Separately, run the [Aspect](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/aspect.htm) tool on the original DEM
> 5. Run the Reclassify tool, so that cell values within your aspect range (however you define South) = 100, and all other degrees = 0

*Now you have two raster layers*

> 6. Run the [Raster Calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) tool, and add the two raster layers together

*Now you have a bunch of cells that are valued 0,10,100, and 110. The 110 value are the cells that meet your criteria (south and with slope).*

> 7. Finally, run the Reclassify tool again so that cells that equal 110 = 1, and all other values = 0

*Now you have a layer with cells in two values (those that meet your criteria, and those that don't.)*